# Azure Cognitive Search - limit queries to documents in specific subpath on autocomplete

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

In Azure Cognitive Search we have documents indexed with a path field and would like to use queries limited to documents in a specific sub path. Example:

For documents:

```
    /content/root/foldera/sub1/sub11
    /content/root/foldera/sub1/sub12
    /content/root/foldera/sub2/sub11
    /content/root/folderb/sub1/sub11
```

Search for content under /content/root/foldera/sub1.

Normally we would filter with search.ismatch('/content/root/foldera/sub1'), but we also want to use the filter in autocomplete queries that do no allow search.ismatch filtering.

We added a custom Analyzer that uses the PathHierarchyTokenizerV2, assuming that this would allow us to search with equals on the individual path fragments/tokens:

```
{
   "name": "path",
   "type": "Edm.String",
   "searchable": true,
   "filterable": true,
   "sortable": false,
   "facetable": false,
   "analyzer": "path_hierarchy"
},
  ...
 "analyzers": [
   {
      "name": "path_hierarchy",
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "charFilters": [],
      "tokenizer": "my_path_tokenizer",
      "tokenFilters": []
   }
],
"charFilters": [],
"tokenizers": [
   {
      "name": "my_path_tokenizer",
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.PathHierarchyTokenizerV2"
   }
]
```

`

When using the analyze query we see the path tokenized as expected. We are now wondering how we would be able to filter so it only includes documents from a partial path. Running a query with eq only works with exact matches, but not on pages below that path:

```
{
    "filter": "path eq '/content/root/foldera/sub1'",
    "select": "path"
}
```

Is there a way to filter for a sub path without using search.ismatch?

Thank you